# Run php script on CLI with interactive output

Tags: php, command-line-interface, output

When I run my PHP script on my local windows machine, I see the output of `printf` every time it is called.

But running on a remote CentOS 6 machine using `php index.php -x` does not show any output until it has finished execution. How can I enable `printf` to write sth to the output stream every time it is called, so I can see what my script is actually doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to use `fwrite(STDOUT, "text")` instead of `printf` as noted [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-command-line-1/)